# Query hangs before execution(query plan takes ages)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to execute following query below (on Hive tables), but for some reason it hangs even before it start executing. Just hangs after I paste it to REPL, and also nothing appear in the WEB UI.

Spark shell is started with following parameters:

```
$ spark-shell --num-executors=10 --executor-cores=3 --executor-memory=16G --conf spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true
```

testtable has a few records and testtable_stg has around 100 million records. There are 15 columns in the query, I just include 6 in here to simplify it.

```
{
     {
       spark.table("testtable_stg")
         .selectExpr(
           """md5(concat(coalesce(nullif(test1,'null'),'val'),
             coalesce(nullif(test2,'null'),'val'),
             coalesce(nullif(test3,'null'),'val'),
             coalesce(nullif(test4,'null'),'val'),
             cast(coalesce(test5,'2222-22-22') as date),
           )) as sk""",
           "coalesce(nullif(test1,'null'),'val') as test1",
           "coalesce(nullif(test2,'null'),'val') as test2",
           "coalesce(nullif(test3,'null'),'val') as test3",
           "coalesce(nullif(test4,'null'),'val') as test4",
           "cast(coalesce(test5,'2222-22-22') as date) as test5",
           "CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) AS TIMESTAMP) as dt"
         )
     }.join(spark.table("testtable"), Seq("sk"), "leftanti")
       .write
       .format("parquet")
       .mode("Append")
       .saveAsTable("testtable")
}
```

When I paste it to REPL without write, then it's fine. But when I want to call any action on this df (i.e. show, save) or even explain plan then it freezes.

I guess I will find eventually the solution to run this query. But I am more interested in Spark behavior here, that its just hangs. I am running thousands of queries on this cluster. But usually I get some information back (i.e. warning, error, etc...). But in this specific query it just hangs.

> UPDATE

I started removing columns one by one from the select statement, and finally I got the query plan. Less columns, the query plan was produced faster. However, with all the columns it takes ages, because seems like query plan is being produced so long before executing the query. Is there any way to speed it up? I tried to increase memory on driver, but no luck. I am using spark 2.1 and 2.2.

Comment: please try `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage", false)`

Comment: Nope it didn't help, after pasting query to REPL its just freezing :) It's really strange behavior. I will try to modify query to do NULLIF and COALESCE in two steps. I will see if that will help. My guess is that the plan just can't be built due to complexity in the SELECT statement. But that would be strange.

Comment: This should be easy to debug since it happens on the driver process - try to profile the process on local mode and see where it spends most of it's time. It's really weird that disabling codegen didn't help =\

Comment: Seems like when I remove COALESCE and NULLIF from MD5 function, then the plan is generated in a second. But with them it's a problem and after waiting 20 minutes  I just give up :)

Comment: are there a lot of tiny files in one of those table ? if there are thousands or millions of tiny files, and the backend storage is something like s3, driver may take a lot of time just to list those files before deciding on some query optimizations etc..